# how do i create the customised array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [418] => Albania
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [5] => Andorra
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [6] => Angola
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [8] => Antigua and Barbuda
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [9] => Argentina
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [486] => Armenia
        )
);
```

How do i get the array like as below from the above array

```
Array
    (
        [418] => Albania
        [5] => Andorra
        [6] => Angola
        [8] => Antigua and Barbuda
        [9] => Argentina
        [486] => Armenia
    )
```

Comment: `foreach ($outerArray as $innerArray) { $outputArray[array_keys($innerArray)[0]] = array_values($innerArray)[0]; }` would be a first (fragile) approach

Comment: why is this tagged with cakePHP?

Comment: @Alex because for whatever reason it seems to be fun to tag everything with CakePHP. I've noticed this "trend" some time ago. I removed the CakePHP tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$a = [[418=>'Albania'],[5=>'Andorra'],[6=>'Angola'],[8=>'Antigua and Barbuda'],[4=>'Argentina'],[486=>'Armenia']];
$b = array();

foreach($a as $aEntry) {
    $b += $aEntry;
}

print_r($b);
```

This will work, provided the country codes are unique.